# Как реализовать механизм перебора уникальных значений в массиве с помощью рекурсии? (для решения задачи поиска чисел Армстронга)

Tags: java, алгоритм, рекурсия, числа

Задача такова: нужно найти все числа Армстронга, меньше N. Один источник подсказал, что перебор "уникальных" комбинаций можно осуществить с помощью массива long[], длинной в N ячеек. Сначала заполняем все ячейки числом 9. Затем проводится уменьшение на 1 значения в [0] элементе массива до тех пор, пока это значение не достигнет 0. Тогда уменьшается значение элемента с индексом [1], а все предыдущие элементы также получают это новое значение. Пример: [0, 9, 9] становится [8, 8, 9]. После этого массив снова декрементируется по описанной выше схеме, начиная с [0] элемента.

Что-то подсказывает что это проще реализовать через рекурсию, но как?

Пока получился только такой корявый кусок кода:

```
    int[] target = new int[numbLength(N)];
    Arrays.fill(target, 9);

    // очередная попытка написать рабочий цикл

    for (int i = 0; i < target.length; i++) {

        for (int j = 8; j >= 0 ; j--) {               
                                                        
                for (int k = i; k >= 0; k--)
                    target[k] = j;


            if (i != 0) {

               

                    for (int m = target[0]; m >= 0; m--) {
                        target[0] = m;
                        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(target));
                    }
                
            }
            else
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(target));

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

В своё время решал по схеме предложенной [тут](https://acmp.ru/article.asp?id_text=198).
По Вашему предложению. Массив скорее всего (это не точно) придётся копировать по значению, а не по ссылке. Если это не сделать, то это может привести к непонятным изменениям в самом массиве. На этом утверждении не настаиваю, т.к. точно не уверен в нём. Но если это так, то это дикие, для данной задачи, накладные расходы на память. Один массив int длиной 1E6 это 4Mb. И это умножить на количество рекурсий.
Не знаю какие условия у Вас стоят, но когда я её решал, то меня ограничивали по времени и памяти. И как по мне задача не особо напрашивается на рекурсию.

З.Ы. К делу абсолютно не относится, но сама задача абсолютно бесполезная. Единственный её плюс - понимание того, что тупой перебор - плохой вариант. И всё. Это не стоит затраченного времени на реализацию и попытку придумать что-то интересное:(